# get transformation matrix from three known points

Tags: matrix, transformation, pitch

i have three 3d (x,y,z) points.
i get them by tracking the corners an object with a kinect.

i now want to translate and rotate a 3d model accordingly.

i get roll and pitch by doing this:
(i am using openframeworks.cc so some of the class methods might seem strange to people)

```
ofVec3f v10 = pointB - pointA;
ofVec3f v20 = pointC - pointA;  


v10.normalize();
v20.normalize();

//create rotation matrix for roll+pitch relative to up vector 0,0,1
ofVec3f normaleVec = v10.crossed(v20);
ofVec3f fromVec = ofVec3f(0,0,1);       
ofVec3f toVec = normaleVec;

mMR0.makeRotationMatrix(fromVec,toVec);
```

to get the heading / yaw i do this:
    ofVec3f myV0_flat = avePointA*mMR0.getInverse();
    ofVec3f myV1_flat = avePointB*mMR0.getInverse();

```
//get points relative to origion
ofVec3f myV10_flat = myV1_flat - myV0_flat;
//create rotation matrix for heading relative to flat 2d plane
float angle = atan2(myV10_flat.x,myV10_flat.y)/M_PI*180;

mMR1.makeRotationMatrix(angle,fromVec);
```

and finally create translation matrix and combine all the matrices:

```
    mMT1.makeTranslationMatrix(avePointD); //translate from origin 


ofMatrix4x4 mMc;
mMc = mMR0 * mMR1 * mMT1;
```

but when my 3d model rotates around it seems to dip always at the same angle.

my question is. how would i calculate roll and pitch separately, so i can where it dips and how to fix it.

thx.
s.